# Processing - keep getting "The function sub(PVector, PVector) does not exist"

Tags: processing

I'm trying to code a simple 'follow the mouse' program, however the following code throws an error saying that the static .sub() method doesn't exist:

```java
void update()
  {
    PVector mouse = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    PVector direction = PVector.sub(mouse, location); // dir = mouse - location

    direction.normalise();
    direction.multiply(0.4);

    acceleration = direction;

    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(maxVelocity);
    location.add(velocity);
  }
```

I have defined some of the methods myself (method overloading?), hence why we have 'multiply' instead of 'mult' etc. etc., but I can't understand why it's telling me .sub() doesn't exist, when it's [clearly there in the documentation](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_sub_.html). I have had this for a few other methods too.

Do I need to define my own static .sub()? Can you even do that in Processing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your custom mouse chaser class ? (It's unclear how you're using ```PVector```:party looks like using composition, but partly extending the class, but using the the same name as the super class, which might have something to with it)

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you defined some of the methods yourself doesn't make a ton of sense. Are you using the `PVector` class from Processing, or are you using your own `PVector` class?

If you're using your own `PVector` class, then you're either going to have to define your own `sub()` function, or you might be able to use Processing's `PVector` class using its **fully qualified name**, like this:

```java
processing.core.PVector x = processing.core.PVector.sub(y, z);
```

Of course, this will also return a Processing `PVector` instead of your `PVector`.

I'm not sure why you would need to define your own `PVector` class, or why you'd need to define your own `PVector` methods. Something sounds off there.

If this doesn't fix your problem, then please edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any of these methods you've defined yourself, and how you're defining them.

Comment: I'm using my own PVector class, mainly as a learning tool to get used to vector operations in Processing. I found that deleting my PVector class from the project folder fixed my problem, so I'll probably just go with that for now.

Just a quick question - what do you mean by 'fully qualified name'? How does that work?

Comment: @LouisCowell Please see the example code in my answer. See the `processing.core.PVector` part? That's the fully qualified name, and googling something like "Java fully qualified name" will give you a bunch more information. In any case, if you're going to have your own `PVector` class for some reason, at least name it something different so it doesn't interfere with the existing `PVector` class!